# XQuery return doesn't calculate anything

Tags: xml, xquery, saxon

So, there is this exercise we need to do with XQuery. A calculator for operations stored in an XML. This is my first time using XQuery and i am very confused. Whatever I put in my return statements, Saxon returns not the results of functions included in the return segment but just returns it in plain text, so calling:

```
declare function m:evaluate($tree as element()) as element(fraction) {
if(local-name($tree)="fraction") then (

 for $a in $tree
  return
     <fraction>
        <numerator>$tree/numerator</numerator>
        <denominator>$tree/denominator </denominator>
     </fraction>
)
else(

typeswitch($tree)
  case $tree as element(sum)
    return element fraction{
      <numerator>$tree/*[1]/numerator/$tree/*[1]/denominator*$ggT+$tree/*[2]/numerator/$tree/*[2]/denominator*$ggT)</numerator>,
      <denominator>m:findggT($tree/*[1]/denominator,$tree/*[2]/denominator)</denominator>}
  case $tree as element(product)
    return element fraction{
      <numerator>m:evaluate($tree/*[1]/numerator)*m:evaluate($tree/*[2]/numerator)</numerator>,
      <denominator>m:evaluate($tree/*[1]/denominator)*m:evaluate($tree/*[2]/denominator)</denominator>
    }
  default return element fraction  {
      <numerator>$tree/numerator</numerator>,
      <denominator>$tree/denominator </denominator>
  }


)
```

returns

```
<fraction>
   <numerator>m:evaluate($tree/*[1]/numerator)*m:evaluate($tree/*[2]/numerator)</numerator>
   <denominator>m:evaluate($tree/*[1]/denominator)*m:evaluate($tree/*[2]/denominator)</denominator>
</fraction>%
```

Obviously, the root element of the called xml is a `product`.

It seems I missed something about how function calls in XQuery work but I don't know what.

The XML I used is:

```
<product>
  <sum>
    <fraction >
      <numerator >1</numerator >
      <denominator >2</denominator >
    </fraction >
    <fraction >
      <numerator >1</numerator >
      <denominator >3</denominator >
    </fraction >
    <fraction >
      <numerator >1</numerator >
      <denominator >4</denominator >
    </fraction >
  </sum>
  <fraction >
    <numerator >2</numerator >
    <denominator >3</denominator >
  </fraction >
</product >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expressions are treated as text because they are not inside curly braces (`{}`). Curly braces are already part of the [computed element constructor](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-computedConstructors) syntax, but they need to be added when using a [direct element constuctor](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-element-constructor) to differentiate between plain text and expressions:

```
<numerator>{ m:evaluate($tree/*[1]/numerator) * m:evaluate($tree/*[2]/numerator)}</numerator>
```

Comment: Thank you. that worked. i got alot of other problems now. Is there a good way to debug xquery (e.g. when i get "empty argument not allowed in..." and i want to know what happens)?

Comment: @MariusRom OxygenXML is a nice text editor that will highlight errors in your code. However, it's probably faster to just read the error and line number returned by the Saxon debugger and look at your code :)